# R function to extract top n scores from a dataframe and find their average using `apply` or dplyr `rowwise`

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

The dataframe looks like this

```
df = data.frame(name = c("A","B","C"),
               exam1 = c(2,6,4),
               exam2 = c(3,5,6),
               exam3 = c(5,3,3),
               exam4 = c(1,NA,5))
```

I want to extract the top 3 exam scores for each 'name' and find their average using **apply()** or dplyr **rowwise()** functions.

Comment: FYI, use three backticks \`\`\` for a code block - one or more lines of code where the whole line is code. For code formatting within a normal text line a single backtick \` is all that is needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `apply`, use `MARGIN = 1`, to loop over the rows on the numeric columns, `sort`, get the `head/tail` depending on `decreasing = TRUE/FALSE` and return with the `mean` in `base R`

```
apply(df[-1], 1, FUN = function(x) mean(head(sort(x, decreasing = TRUE), 3)))
[1] 3.333333 4.666667 5.000000
```

---

Or with `dplyr/rowwise`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(Mean = mean(head(sort(c_across(where(is.numeric)), 
       decreasing = TRUE), 3))) %>% 
  ungroup
# A tibble: 3 × 6
  name  exam1 exam2 exam3 exam4  Mean
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         2     3     5     1  3.33
2 B         6     5     3    NA  4.67
3 C         4     6     3     5  5
```

Comment: thank you! is there a what to use top_n?

Comment: Much appreciate the rapid response from all.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative approach with pivoting and using `top_n`: This will give back only the top 3:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -name,
    names_to = "exam",
    values_to = "value"
  ) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  top_n(3, value) %>% 
  mutate(mean = mean(value)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = exam, 
    values_from = value
  )
```

```
  name   mean exam1 exam2 exam3 exam4
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A      3.33     2     3     5    NA
2 B      4.67     6     5     3    NA
3 C      5        4     6    NA     5
```

OR:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -name,
    names_to = "exam",
    values_to = "value"
  ) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  top_n(3, value) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(value))
```

```
 name   mean
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A      3.33
2 B      4.67
3 C      5
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `purrr::pmap_dfr`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df = data.frame(name = c("A","B","C"),
                exam1 = c(2,6,4),
                exam2 = c(3,5,6),
                exam3 = c(5,3,3),
                exam4 = c(1,NA,5))

df %>% 
  pmap_dfr(~ list(means = mean(sort(c(..2,..3,..4,..5), decreasing=T)[1:3]))) %>%
  bind_cols(df,.)

#>   name exam1 exam2 exam3 exam4    means
#> 1    A     2     3     5     1 3.333333
#> 2    B     6     5     3    NA 4.666667
#> 3    C     4     6     3     5 5.000000
```

---

Another possible solution, based on `tidyr::pivot_longer` and without using `rowwise`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df = data.frame(name = c("A","B","C"),
                exam1 = c(2,6,4),
                exam2 = c(3,5,6),
                exam3 = c(5,3,3),
                exam4 = c(1,NA,5))

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = 2:5, names_to = "names") %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  slice_max(value, n=3) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(value)) %>% 
  inner_join(df)

#> Joining, by = "name"
#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   name   mean exam1 exam2 exam3 exam4
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 A      3.33     2     3     5     1
#> 2 B      4.67     6     5     3    NA
#> 3 C      5        4     6     3     5
```

Answer (score 1):

I went back to the question and tried using basic dplyr manipulation of 'df' which also works, much like some of the really helpful solutions in earlier posts.

```
df_long <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -name,
               names_to = "exam",
               values_to = "score")
df_long %>%
group_by(name) %>% 
  arrange(desc(score)) %>% 
  slice(1:3) %>% 
  summarise(mean_score = mean(score))
```

@Paul Smith nice idea to add `inner_join(df)`

Answer (score 1):

I would take @akrun and add the `na.rm` parameter, just in case you need it in future approach where the top scores can search though NA results.

The final results would be:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("A","B","C"),
                exam1 = c(2,6,4),
                exam2 = c(3,5,6),
                exam3 = c(5,3,3),
                exam4 = c(1,NA,5))

results <- apply(df[-1], 1, FUN = function(x) mean(
head(sort(x, decreasing = TRUE), 3),
na.rm=TRUE))

names(results) <- df$name 

results
```

The results should look like this:

```
> results
       A        B        C 
3.333333 4.666667 5.000000 
>
```